# Crinteria Join make AND insetad of OR

Tags: java, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

My problem is that wen i set cb.or it do cb and.. cb is CriteriaBuilder
My class is :

```
public class User extends BaseEntity<User> {
public static final String CHILDREN_FIELD = "children";
public static final String PARENT_FIELD = "parent";

//Id column based in BaseEntity

OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)
JoinColumn(name = "parent_partner_id")
User parent;

OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = LAZY,cascade = {})
private List<User> children;
```

My criteria code is :

```
Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
Join<User, User> userJoin = root.join(CHILDREN_FIELD, JoinType.LEFT);
userJoin.on(
cb.or(
cb.equal(userJoin.get(ID_FIELD), root.get("id")))
);
```

Code generates :

```
select
user0_.id as col_0_0_
from
user user0_
left outer join
user children2_
on user0_.id=children2_.parent_id
and (  <- i write OR in cb!! why it generates AND ?  
children2_.id=user0_.id
)
```

How can I resolve it? Why my code generates AND statement?

Comment: Hi, does this query make sense on a SQL point of view ? I dont get it.

Comment: I use postgesql

Answer (score 1):

Probably that's because you have a single argument in your **or** method call

```
cb.or(cb.equal(userJoin.get(ID_FIELD), root.get("id"))));
```

should be

```
cb.or(arg1, arg2); // arg1 OR arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that with API criteria it is not possible today, I will tell you about different options:

1.- Use native query

The use of native query is not a problem since you are using clauses supported by all DB managers

```
List<User> result =  em.createNativeQuery("select * from user p "+
                        "left outer join user p1 on p.id = p1.parent_id or p.id = p1.id", 
                        "User.nativeConstructorMapping").getResultList();
```

In your entity

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name="User.nativeConstructorMapping",
    classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = Users.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class)
            [...]
        })
    })
})

....

public User(Long id, String name, [...]) {
    super();
    this.id= id;
    this.name = name
    [...]
}
```

2.- Use two roots, in case inner join would serve you instead of left join adding the conditions of the on clause in the where

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root1 = query.from(User.class);
Root<User> root2 = query.from(User.class);

query.where(cb.or(
    cb.equal(root1.get(User_.id),root2.get(User_.parent).get(User_.id)),
    cb.equal(root1.get(User_.id),root2.get(User_.id)))
);
```

As I was telling you, although it is not recommended to use native queries because it breaks with the JPA philosophy, in this case as you do not use the clauses of any DB it should not be a problem, I would be the option I would choose.